# CouchDB - Top N documents for each group

Tags: architecture, couchdb, couchbase

I'm evaluating CouchDB at the moment, by walking along a couple of common use-cases we will encounter in our webproject.

One of these use-cases is the following:

Consider a system containing (contrived example):

- articles
- questions
- topics

articles and questions can be assigned to multiple topics.

A topic has it's own page (think of http://www.quora.com topics).

Is it possible with 1 query from couchdb to get BOTH:

- the latest N articles on topic X
- AND the latest N (or M?) questions on topic X

In more generic terms: I'm looking for a way to do a group by type (where, in this case,  type = 'article' or 'question' ) and for each group return the top n documents given a certain sort (in this case sort is reverse chronological) constrained to a specific filter (in this case the topic 'X')

From what I've read, it's often not that big a deal to do multiple couchdb-queries in parallel, from a performance standpoint, but I'm just curious if this (for us often used ) use-case can be done in a single request.

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

CouchDB views are 1-dimensional. For a given topic, the most recent articles AND the most recent questions is a two-dimensional query and thus not possible in one HTTP request.

### Thoughts on a workaround

CouchDB is architected for, and encourages concurrent queries. In production, I would make two queries from my other answer concurrently. (In Javascript, this is very easy, but any asynchronous or threaded programming language can do it.)

The response time to receive *both* results will only be the response time of the longer result (i.e. the one that finishes first was "free"). You can even walk the rows of *both* responses to merge their timelines in O(1) space and O(n) time—not too bad!

The only thing that CouchDB does not guarantee is that both queries represent snapshots of the exact same database state. You mention Quora and that is a perfect example of modern database requirements. **In theory**, you have no idea how much database state has changed between these two queries. You have no idea, generally, if one view makes any sense compared to the other. **In practice**, the answer is obvious: *Who cares?* Queries separated by mere milliseconds will, in reality, make perfect sense together. That is why CouchDB is well-suited for web-applications despite having a severely restricted feature set.

### Alternative solution: GeoCouch

The GeoCouch extension is actually a general-purpose 2-dimensional bounding box query engine. Besides, obviously, geospatial data, it can be used, for example, to query logs stored as a `timestamp` x `severity` 2-space. However it is currently still a separate project from CouchDB so I would be reluctant to call it a "CouchDB query."

Comment: Thanks. I am correct in thinking that this doesn't have to be a performance problem right? Requests get cached anyhow, etc. I think I was just being over-zealous in trying to  combine it all, when needing multiple requests sometimes is not so bad.

Comment: Note, I expanded my answer just before your comment, not sure if you saw it. I think there is definitely a cost to multiple requests: more complex client code, more chance of bugs. A cynical view is that CouchDB outsources the hard work to the application developer. My feeling is, just as there are general-purpose languages and domain-specific languages, there are general-purpose databases and domain-specific databases. CouchDB's strengths are simple HTTP APIs and also replication. So the "cost" can be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for expanding: I indeed missed it. Excellent to hear CouchDB is indeed architected for concurrent querying. I'll be going the concurrent route (in both Java and JS). 'staleness' is no concern for us so no problem there. For some it may indeed be a good idea, but we won't go the GeoCouch-route: what if we need pics, reviews, comments, etc. per topic as well in the future. We need an N-dimensional general purpose bounding-box implementation. Not sure if that's coming around any-time soon :).. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with 1 query from CouchDB to get both. Both queries use a map/reduce query, although you do not need the reduce function.

You need the view rows to have `[$type, $topic, $timestamp]` pairs for keys:

```
["article" , "money", "2011-09-21T20:50:29.819Z"]
["article" , "shoes", "2011-09-21T20:30:29.819Z"]
["article" , "shoes", "2011-09-21T20:50:29.819Z"]
["question", "grits", "2011-01-13T20:30:18.123Z"]
["question", "money", "2011-09-20T20:30:18.123Z"]
```

This function might do that:

```
function(doc) {
    // _design/my_app/_view/topic_parts
    var key;

    if(doc.type && doc.parent_topic && doc.created_at) {
        // Looks good, emit it into the view.
        key = [doc.type, doc.parent_topic, doc.created_at];
        emit(key, doc);
    }
}
```

To find the latest N rows (whether articles or questions), you basically need rows matching `[$type, $topic, *]` in descending order. For example, for the latest **N articles** on topic **X**, that breaks down like this. (Note that `null` is the smallest value in CouchDB and the object `{}` is the largest.)

- `descending=true` to get reverse chronological order. (Note "descending" conceptually means couch is scanning from the "bottom" to the "top" of the rows. So *startkey and endkey are reversed*.)
- `startkey=["articles","X",{}]`, so this is **articles** about **X** starting from the end of time
- `endkey=["articles","X",null]`, this is the same **articles** about **X** ending with the beginning of time
- `limit=N`, to trim the results down

The query would thus look like this (remember to encode the URL if necessary).

```
GET /db/_design/my_app/_view/topic_parts?descending=true&startkey=["articles","X",{}]&endkey=["articles","X",null]&limit=N
```

Comment: looks great, but doesn't the final query `GET /db/_design/my_app/_view/topic_parts?descending=true&startkey=["articles","X",{}]&endkey=["articles","X",null]&limit=N` just ONLY display top N articles? Instead of top N articles AND top N questions?

Comment: to clarify: you started your answer with saying: "it is possible with 1 query from CouchDB to get both". But in the end your query would result in only giving 'articles' not (articles AND questions). Any hint on how to extend your reply to include these? Or is it not possible in hindsight?

Comment: I read your question to mean you wanted each bullet point in one query, not both together. Please see my second answer.